# Error when Reading from a Large Data Lake Store

Tags: ssis, azure-data-lake

I have an SSIS package reading web data from Azure Data Lake through the component called Azure Data Lake Store Source Editor.

The data, I am reading is large and web-based data, i.e. there are lots of unreadable stuff in it.

The data is JSON and I don't want to parse the data in the Source component. I am parsing it in another component (script transformation editor). I just need a delimiter that says SSIS not to try to parse the data.

All is fine for an hour or two. SSIS is loading the data for many files, but then I get the error.

Error:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponentHResultException (0xC02090F5): Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC02090F5 from a method call. at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.AdlsComponents.PipelineComponentSource.TransferToOutputBuffers(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
```

After some investigation, I found that this is what you get when the delimiter is part of the data.

Almost every character I tried in the ASCII table and I am still getting the error after some processing.

Do you have any idea:

- Is there a way to bypass the delimiter?
- Is there a delimiter you can recommend (may be some control characters) that can never be used as data?

Thanks for reading & considering

Comment: Did you try the Bell character (code 7) (when read, the computer beeps) or
the null character (code 0), or the End of File marker?